# Manually trigger Azure Function with extra data

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I found out that you can manually trigger Time Trigger Azure function [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http) and in step number 7 there is a way to pass dictionary, but there is no example on how to read this information. If that is not possible I tried to read how to make fire and forget http request just to trigger my calculations, but that also is not that resalable to do, so in the end I left with durable functions this could be okay, but in this case it would be a bit overkill.

Use case:
Some date is processed daily during a night (Time trigger) and takes default value "Today", but for example data provider was down, but in few days it is up and running, I need a way to reprocess for previous days. Http call will timeout because it takes for example 1 hour and so on.

Maybe someone have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

For process previous day data you can use fromdays(-1) for previous days data process.

```cs
DateTime previous_day= context.CurrentUtcDateTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(-1)); 
await context.CreateTimer(previous_day, CancellationToken.None); 
await context.CallActivityAsync("Function1_ProcessPreviousDays");
```

```cs
[FunctionName("Function1_ProcessPreviousDays")]
        public static string processdata([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log)
        {
            // apply logic here
            
            return $"Process Previous Days Data!";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for this sample, this would use durable functions, but my main point is there a way, there I could use time trigger and pass extra data with master key to function to manually invoke it, or how I would use "fire and forget" technique to start processing without needing to start using durable functions.

Comment: You can not pass data in timer trigger Azure function.